# "Not an ARRAY reference" error starts to happen when I modularize my code

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm modularizing my code, but when I move a `sub` out of it's original module, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't load application from file "foo.pl": Not an ARRAY reference at D.pm line 10.
```

This was the original file. As is, it's all ok:

`FormerC.pm`:

```
package FormerC;

use strict;

my %my_hash = ( key => 'value' );
my @my_array = qw( some strings inside array );

sub problematic_sub {
  my ($hash_ref, $array_ref) = @_;

  my @an_array = @$array_ref;

  return \@an_array;
};

sub uses_problematic_sub {
  problematic_sub(\%my_hash, \@my_array);
};

uses_problematic_sub();

1
```

These are the two new modules. With these I get the error:

`D.pm`:

```
package D;

use strict;

sub new { bless {}, shift };

sub problematic_sub {
  my ($hash_ref, $array_ref) = @_;

  my @an_array = @$array_ref;

  return \@an_array;
};

1
```

`C.pm`:

```
package C;

use strict;

use D;
my $d = D->new;

my %my_hash = ( key => 'value' );
my @my_array = qw( some strings inside array );

sub uses_problematic_sub {
  $d->problematic_sub(\%my_hash, \@my_array);
};

uses_problematic_sub();

1
```

Comment: Also, don't use `B`. There's a core module by that name.

Comment: This doesn't show the problem because `uses_problematic_sub` is never called.

Comment: @ikegami The names are better than there. They were just examples to show the error appearing. But thanks anyway. Won't use it in further questions.

Comment: @Borodin again, it was just because I wanted to keep the code samples small. But ok, One extra line wouldn't hurt. I'll update the code to call `uses_problematic_sub`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely to be better off using the [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/module/Exporter) module to export the subroutine names into the calling code's namespace. What you have written here is an object-oriented module, but the object is just a collection of subroutines and doesn't need object-oriented support.

The problem is that a method call like

```
$d->problematic_sub(\%my_hash, \@my_array)
```

implicitly passes the object as the first parameter, so it is equivalent to

```
D::problematic_sub($d, \%my_hash, \@my_array)
```

All you need to do is account for this in the subroutine

```
sub problematic_sub {

  my ($self, $hash_ref, $array_ref) = @_;

  my @an_array = @$array_ref;

  return \@an_array;
}
```

and your code should work.

Also note that a subroutine declaration, like a `while` or `for` loop, is *not* a statement and so doesn't need and shouldn't have a semicolon after it.

Comment: Thanks! I try `Exporter`. Feels like it's the best approach for me. I miss Ruby's `include` so much =(

Answer (score 5):

You used to call `problematic_sub` as a sub

```
problematic_sub(\%my_hash, \@my_array);
```

but you now call is as a method:

```
$d->problematic_sub(\%my_hash, \@my_array);
```

Since you didn't code `problematic_sub` as a method, this isn't correct. You need to also change `problematic_sub`'s parameters to the following:

```
my ($self, $hash_ref, $array_ref) = @_;
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand it. But I really wanted something like `Exporter`. It was not what I asked for, but it was what I wanted to do in the end.